# unwanted javascript being generated on my template causing HTML warning

Tags: javascript, html

I am validating my HTML template on firefox validator and there is this error that kept on showing. 
whenever I check my  HTML file on the said line I don't see the line of script that firefox see.

**here is the error**
->
 [image]

**here is the html file**
->
[image]

[image: updated image]
[image: updated image]

Comment: Line 36 of the validation and the line(s) you show in the picture differ. Can you just directly paste the generated HTML? (specifically around line 36 [maybe a few lines before and a few lines after])

Comment: The error is about a `<script>` element. Not a `<div>` as depicted in your image.

Comment: Please post your include script and relevant html code. For the future, post info as text not images.

Comment: @joren I was showing the image on my editor to show you that line 36 does'nt have any script element.

Comment: That's because your html can change after you've loaded the page

Answer (score 0):

That doesnt look like its a part of your code, looks like bitdefender injecting html into your browser. http://forum.bitdefender.com/index.php?showtopic=33381